# Photon flux for coherent waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, photons, field-theory

Coherent waves posses a well defined phase and thus not a well defined photon count. On the other hand (according to Hecht in his book "Optics" eq 3.49) we can define a mean photon flux for quasi monochromatic waves. Measuring the photon count is now Poisson distributed in accordance with the given mean photon flux. I now have a few questions:

1. In the book only measurements with a long exposure time $T$ compared to a wave period are considered and the mean photon flux density is given by
   $$ \Phi(t) = (\hbar \omega T)^{-1} \int_{t-T/2}^{t+T/2} E \times H d t.$$
   If we now considered a detector with a really short exposure time would this formula still hold?
   If so, can we thus define a momentary quantity $(\hbar \omega)^{-1} E \times H$ representing the mean photon flux density at a given point in space and time. This would mean that similar to energy the mean photon density would oscillate during a wave period. I was thinking that this would probably violate Heisenberg uncertainty somehow.
2. Is it possible to extend the mean photon flux to general wave packets with arbitrary spectral functions?